# Redactor with no toolbar

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, redactor

I am using jquery redactor and all is good but I want to make some sections behave like an edit-in-place editor.

I understand how buttons work e.g.:

```
var buttons = ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic'];

$('#redactor').redactor({buttons: buttons});
```

And have set buttons to:

```
var buttons = [];
```

So no buttons, but, toolbar still shows.

**QUESTION** Is there a way to remove the toolbar as well as the buttons?

Answer (score 5):

If you set `buttons` with a empty array you use default setting:

```
['html', '|', 'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|',
'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|',
'image', 'video', 'file', 'table', 'link', '|',
'fontcolor', 'backcolor', '|', 'alignment', '|', 'horizontalrule']
```

So, you can set `toolbar` setting like this :

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
   toolbar: false
});
```

And if you want the toolbar is loaded in a separate layer from the editor:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    toolbarExternal: '#your-toolbar-id'
});
```

Documentation: http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, with the help of the `toolbar` property:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({toolbar: false});
```

*Reference:* http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/

Answer (score 0):

After dragging a div from the document i want to focus on the editable redactor.
How to trigger focus function on redactor editable area?

I tried:

```
$('#'+maskId).draggable({
  containment: '#content',
  drag: function(){
    // ...
  },
  stop: function() {
    $('#'+redactorTextareaId).redactor({
      focus: true
    });
  }
});
```

and:

```
$('#'+maskId).draggable({
  containment: '#content',
  drag: function(){
    // ...
  },
  stop: function() {
    $('#'+redactorTextareaId).focus();
  }
});
```